# Electron add button to dismiss modal BrowserWindow

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm building a Mac app using electron and react, and I'm using a modal window to redirect my users to the google login page using the `loadURL` method.

[image]

This causes that the whole window is covered by the modal dialog, with no way for the user to return to the previous page unless he finishes the google login flow.

I would like to have a header on top with a back button so that the user can dismiss the modal if needed. Can I insert HTML to the `BrowserWindow` after it has loaded the url content? Or is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: You can make an HTML "mask" with a webview inside for the content. In this way you can have your buttons and function and inside a component a simil iframe but with a lot more control functions.